# angular passing variables to child component, skip intermediate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular app (angular 1.5) has several different components which are distributed over the whole screen and I want to pass arguments between them.
The page has the following structure:

```
<div id="semanticParent">
    <div id="ui-component1">
        <div id="ui-component2">
            <div id="semanticChild">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each of those `divs` is a seperate component with an isolated scope, where the `ui-components` are 3rd party libraries which handle only the appearance and should not be influenced by the application logic.

One way I can think of to solve this is to create a service which is injected to `semanticParent` and `semanticChild` and all variables are passed through that service, but that doesn't seem really good.

So what is the angular way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it depends on your functional needs :

1) If the parent is owner of the data (it create/edits the data) and the child only read it, you should nest the child component in the parent and pass the data through attributes.

2) If both parent and child can edit and read the data, it is better to make them interact with the data through a service which can ensure the consistency of the data.

I don't know if my answer is what you need but I hope it will clarify.

Comment: a little bit of both, I guess, the child should be able to change the data, but the parent owns it, so if the parent is destroyed and recreated, the data can be different, so the service also has to reload it

Comment: Then use a service. The parent will be able to active/disable the data and the child will have access to it. Even if two-way data-binding is allowed in component's attribute, modify it from the child isn't a good practise.